# Outlook: Custom Pop-Up with logic before sending email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

A colleague had a brilliant idea to reinforce the use of Slack for internal emails. We thought about a custom pop-up that would appear when the user is about to send an internal email. This message would say "Please prefer Slack for internal communication. Are you sure you still want to send?".

I thought about using the Application.ItemSend Event in VBA to trigger the pop-up.
I do not have much experience in VBA but I found that snippet to get me started:

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 

 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 

End Sub 



Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 

 Dim prompt As String 

 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 

 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 

 Cancel = True 

 End If 

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Cancel parameter must be declared "ByRef".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the snippet you found is perfect and talks about `WithEvents` instance property. Now it can't be declared inside standard module. Either you need to put in a class or inside `ThisOutlookSession`

---

Using Class for hooking application level events is the recommended way. But considering your statement *I do not have much experience in VBA* here is one class less way.

---

But for your requirements, all you need to do is put your code inside the `Application_ItemSend` under `ThisOutlookSession`. This way you can avoid creating a class and initializing it at the startup.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim prompt As String

    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"

    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code goes in **ThisOutlookSession**

[image]